# Convert the output of a function into a structure in matlab

Tags: matlab

I wondered  if it could be that a function of the type

```
[output1,output2,...] = function(arg1,arg2,...);
```

thus with multiple outputs (in this case `output1`, `output2`,... are vectors but could be everything else) could be called by assigning it to a structure without having to write

```
[Structure.output1,Structure.output2,...] = function(arg1,arg2,...);
```

In other words, how (if it's possible and I doubt it) something approaching this could work?

```
structure.[output1,output2,...] = function(arg1,arg2,...);
```

The reason why I ask this is because I have a looot of outputs... But I admit this is some laziness :p

Comment: If you wrote `function` yourself, then you can just make it output a struct. Otherwise write an intermediate helper function to output it as a struct. Might be a bit neater then the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, but not in a one-liner that you are looking for. Say you have `N` outputs then you can use

```
c = cells(N,1);
[c{:}] = function(arg1,arg2,...);
structure = cell2struct(c, {'output1' 'output2' ...}, 1);
```

Comment: Great. I was not absolutely wanting a one-liner so this is fine ! Thanks